# Using an azure key to get into azure server?

Tags: azure, ssh

I have been given an azure key in the format of:

"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

gibberish...

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

and the following information:

Host: azureserv

HostName: XXX.XXX.XX.XX

User: azureuser

Port: YY

IdentityFile path to file

How to I ssh into the azure server using these information on a mac?

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this is unrelated to programming and off-topic for Stack Overflow. Also, please be mindful of tags. For example: you included `[web]` which has a description stating to not use it. And `[rsa]` doesn't really apply in this context either. I've removed both. Note that general computing questions are supported via SuperUser, and professional server and networking questions are handled by ServerFault. However, as written, I believe this would be off-topic there as well - just not enough detail or specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You add the key in some directory, for example `.ssh` in you home directory. Then set permission of this file (key) to be 600. After this you can use command:

```
ssh -p YY -i /path/to/your_key azureuser@XXX.XXX.XX.XX
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I have looking for the last 3 hours.

Comment: @cleungtech, you are welcome. If you like the answer feel free to accept/upvote :)

Comment: I tried before and it gave me a message "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."